# Bashing Script within a Script

Tags: bash, scripts, sshfs

I wrote a little script which allows me to connect two a couple of servers via SSHFS. The script sets the variables or puts in defaults if nothing is entered i.e. SSH port 22.

I want to create a script that allows me to type 1, 2, or 3, and connect to

1. SSHFS script where I input variables
2. SSHFS Server 1
3. SSHFS Server 2

With the main aim to be that I don't need to type in username, password, server name etc, each time I connect Via SSHFS.

What's the best way of structuring this so I don't have to repeat my SSHFS line

The variables feed this line.

```
sshfs -o allow_other,defer_permissions -o volname=$USER@$SERVERNAME $USER@$SERVERNAME:$REMOTEMOUNT $LOCALMOUNT -p$PORTNUMBER
```

If I use switch case do I need to include it in each switch case or is there someway to structure it so this line is only included once.

Comment: It's hard to say without actually seeing the scripts, but it may be easiest to put everything in one script. For example, define some functions, then have a case statement which determines which function to run. It if each function would do the same thing just with different arguments, then define one function and feed it different options depending on the case statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, don't use `$USER`. That's a default environmental variable that holds the current user's username. If the username is the same in all servers and the machine you're running the script on, then fine. But if not, use a different name. In general, avoid using UPPER CASE variable names in bash since the default reserved ones are all capitalized.

That said, you could do something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
case $1 in
    1)
        user="user1"
        servername="server1"
        remotemount="remote1"
        localmount="local1"
        portnumber="port1"
        ;;
    2)
        user="user2"
        servername="server2"
        remotemount="remote2"
        localmount="local2"
        portnumber="port2"
        ;;
    3)
        user="user3"
        servername="server3"
        remotemount="remote3"
        localmount="local3"
        portnumber="port3"
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Please use 1, 2 or 3"
        exit 1
        ;;
esac

echo sshfs -o allow_other,defer_permissions -o volname=$user@$servername $user@$servername:$remotemount $localmount -p$portnumber
```

Then, you run your script giving `1`, `2` or `3` as a parameter:

```
foo.sh 2
```

Comment: @wjandrea thanks for the fix, I'd missed that. And thanks for leading me to find out that the final `;;` in a case statement is, apparently, optional! I had the same omission in my test script and it worked as expected. I had no idea!

Comment: Huh. How bizarre...

Comment: thanks, I didn't realise you could run the script with your selection, which is brilliant. saves on requesting it within the script.

Comment: Why do you need to exit with '1' ?

Comment: @denski you don't *need* to, it's just a convention. Normally, upon successful completion, a program exits with a `0` exit code. A non-0 exit code means an error occurred. So, since giving a bad input parameter is an error, I exit with 1. And yes, there is very, very rarely a good reason to have your script request input after launching. 99% of the time, it is better to pass the info to the script when you launch it.